# Compensation of polarization-dependend frequency offset of a passive optical cavity

Tags: quantum-optics, crystals, laser-cavity

I have a passive optical cavity used as an OPO for the generation of squeezed states in pulsed regime, schematized in the following figure.

[image: Scheme of the cavity with a crystal for the generation of squeezed states.]

The crystal used to generate squeezing is a KDP (C1), which type-II phase matching produces a signal and an idler on two orthogonal polarizations (horizontal and vertical). In the figure, the pump is in green, while the propagation of signal and idler is red.
Due to the different refractive index seen by these two polarizations in the KDP crystal, the free-spectral-range is different between horizontal and vertical directions, as well as the frequency offset. For this reason, the two polarizations cannot resonate in the cavity at the same time, but I want them to do. In order to fix this problem, a second identical KDP crystal (C2) can be inserted in the cavity, with axes rotated of 90° around the propagation direction of the beam, so that horizontal and vertical polarizations encounter the opposite refractive index of C1. In the following figure you can see the scheme.

[image: Scheme of the cavity with a crystal for the generation of squeezed states and an identical crystal for the free-spectral-range compensation.]

In this way, the free-spectral-range of signal and idler is exactly the same, but the frequency offset is not.

How can I compensate also the frequency offset?

Notice that I have calculated the different paths using the formulae [here](https://www.fiberoptics4sale.com/blogs/wave-optics/propagation-in-an-anisotropic-medium).